# what does term "emit" in compiler mean?

Tags: terminology

In lots of textbooks and papers, authors often state: compiler emits ...

I want to know why they prefer to use emit? (not return, not produce)

Does this have anything to do with the emitter of a compiler?

thanks

Comment: Could you provide a few examples with the corresponding context?

Comment: Sounds purely related to historical usage of the term emit in papers about compilers.

Comment: Emit is often used with machine or assembly code.

Answer (score 5):

It is mostly used in the sense of "writing instructions to the program being built". Note that what is being "emitted" might still be massaged before ending up in the compiler output.